# How to diagnosis and fix fast battery drain on XPS 15 9560?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, power-management, battery

I recently installed Ubuntu on my XPS 15 9560. The power drainage seems to be very high. When using `powerstat` I saw numbers between `17` and `25` watts. This was with a few applications open and with the brightness set to `40%` I thought that it was the NVIDIA gpu so I ran `prime-select` and saw that it was (or at least thought) that it was using `Intel`. I have `tlp` and  `tlp-rdw` both installed and have updated the kernel to `4.10`. I'm using the proprietary Nvidia drivier (`375.66`). I am not using the proprietary Intel driver. I also have the touch screen disabled. The first part of `powertop` can be found below:

```
Usage     Device name
             27.7%        CPU misc
            229.0 ops/s   GPU misc
             27.7%        DRAM
             27.7%        CPU core
            229.0 ops/s   GPU core
             14.1 pkts/s  Network interface: wlp2s0 (ath10k_pci)
            100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
             30.1%        Display backlight
              0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D2: Intel
            100.0%        Radio device: ath10k_pci
            100.0%        USB device: usb-device-0cf3-e301
            100.0%        USB device: AX88x72A (ASIX Elec. Corp.)
            100.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
            100.0%        USB device: Flash Drive FIT (Samsung)
            100.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
            100.0%        USB device: usb-device-138a-0091
              0.5 pkts/s  Network interface: enx0050b61a1074 (asix)
```

I have the XPS with the high DPI display, 32 GBs of memory and a i7.

Answer (score 1):

**Dell XPS15 9550**, ubuntu 17.4 + kernel 4.12 + native nvidia drivers -
 consumes around 10w-13w on 40% brightness settings.

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```